# How to query CosmosDb for multiple results using SqlQuerySpec

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to get multiple documents using a list of numbers. Here's my query

```
var queryString = "Select * from c Where c.id in (@list)";
var queryParam = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.SqlParameter("@list", string.Join(",", list.Select(x => $"{x.Id}").ToArray()));
var result = repo.Query(
    new SqlQuerySpec()
        {
            QueryText = queryString,
            Parameters = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.SqlParameterCollection()
            {
                queryParam
            }
        }
    );
```

My Query function:

```
public IQueryable<TClass> Query(SqlQuerySpec sqlQuerySpec = null, bool allowScan = false, int? maxItems = null)
    {
        var feedOptions = new FeedOptions
        {
            EnableScanInQuery = allowScan,
            MaxItemCount = maxItems,
            EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true
        };
        var querySpec = sqlQuerySpec ?? new SqlQuerySpec();
        return sqlQuerySpec != null
            ? Client.CreateDocumentQuery<TClass>(Collection.DocumentsLink, querySpec, feedOptions) 
            : Client.CreateDocumentQuery<TClass>(Collection.DocumentsLink, feedOptions);
    }
```

It says there was an error: `one of the specified inputs is invalid`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` is a string so you would need to wrap each id with single quotes.

This line:

```
var queryParam = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.SqlParameter("@list", string.Join(",", list.Select(x => $"{x.Id}").ToArray()));
```

Should be:

```
var queryParam = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.SqlParameter("@list", string.Join(",", list.Select(x => $"'{x.Id}'").ToArray()));
```